# dlib looking for incorrect CUDA version

Tags: python, ubuntu, dlib

I have two machines with Ubuntu 18.04 and identical versions of CUDA (10.2) and dlib (19.19.0). The latter was installed using pip. My python code runs fine on one machine, but fails with

```
   import dlib:
ImportError: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

on the other.

I would like to understand the cause for the different behavior and how to get dlib to use the installed version of CUDA.

Comment: One version of dlib you have installed was built against CUDA 10.0, the other one was built against CUDA 10.2. Either change dlib or change the CUDA version

Comment: @talonmies: Thanks, but I'm working with pip in a virtual environment. The problem remains after deleting the venv and starting from scratch. Are you suggesting there are dlib traces outside the venv?

Comment: I am telling you exactly what the problem is. The CUDA runtime API is versioned and you must have matching CUDA library versions available for a library or framework to work correctly. How you fix it  is a python environment or setup question, and nothing to do with CUDA, which is why I have removed the tag. I  can't help more than that